# Match and Group similar words that are related to each other (relevant) in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, fuzzy-search

It is not just grouping the words in similarities but also meaning. Say that I have the following list:

```
func = ['Police Man','Police Officer','Police','Admin','Administrator','Dietitian','Food specialist','Administrative Assistant','Economist','Economy Consultant']
```

I want to find words with similar meaning and function. I tried fuzzywuzzy but it does not achieve what I want:

```
for i in func:
    for n in func:
        print(i,":",n)
        print(fuzz.ratio(i, n))
```

This is part of the fuzzing and it does not do the job:

```
Dietitian : Dietitian
100
Dietitian : Food specialist
25
```

I believe I should use library nltk or stemming? What is the best approach to find relevant words and functions in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe I should use ... stemming?

You definitely don't want to use stemming. Stemming will only take words to their roots, so stem("running") = "run". It doesn't do anything based on *meaning*, so stem("sprinting") = "sprint" != "run". :(

> I believe I should use nltk ...

[WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) will let you search for sets of synonyms called "synsets" and you can access it through nltk or even through a web interface. It's not great at compound words, though. :( It's mostly just individual words.

So, you can look up ["officer" and "policeman"](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=police%20officer&i=0&h=0#c) and see that they have an overlapping meaning. Of course, "officer" also has OTHER meanings; how close do words have to be to qualify for your search? E.g. if "Food Specialist" is the same as "Dietician", is "Food Specialist" *also* the same as "Chef"?

If WordNet does seem like a useful tool, check out their Python API. You'd want something like

```
common = [synset for synset in wn.synsets("officer") if synset in wn.synsets("policeman")
return len(common) > 0
```